# Multiple If statements for a formula field to show images

Tags: formula, formula-field, image-formula

I am trying to write a formula depending on the count of roll-up summary fields to indicate which color needs to show on the Account object. Here is what I have so far:

```
    IF( OR(Marketing_Sum_Gray__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gray__c > 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m95", "Gray"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Black__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Black__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Gray__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gray__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m90", "Black"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Blue__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Blue__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Black__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Black__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9P", "Blue"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Red__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Red__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Blue__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Blue__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9A", "Red"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Yellow__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Yellow__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Red__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Red__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Yellow"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Green__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Green__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Yellow__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Yellow__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Green"),
    IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Gold__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gold__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Green__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Green__c = 0),         IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Gold"),
    IMAGE("/s.gif", "N/A")))))))
```

Comment: so what is not working here?

Comment: It is saying that I am missing an end ) but no matter how many I try, it's not working

Comment: you can remove one by one condition to figure out the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this Here I add one extra `)` in the end for every if condition for `AND` part.

```
IF( OR(Marketing_Sum_Gray__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gray__c > 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m95", "Gray"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Black__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Black__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Gray__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gray__c = 0)), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m90", "Black"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Blue__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Blue__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Black__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Black__c = 0)), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9P", "Blue"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Red__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Red__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Blue__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Blue__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9A", "Red"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Yellow__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Yellow__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Red__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Red__c = 0)), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Yellow"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Green__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Green__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Yellow__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Yellow__c = 0), IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Green"),
IF(AND(OR(Marketing_Sum_Gold__c > 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Gold__c > 0), OR(Marketing_Sum_Green__c = 0, Outsourcing_Sum_Green__c = 0)),         IMAGE("/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0153C0000004m9o", "Gold"),
        IMAGE("/s.gif", "N/A")))))))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was missing the parenthesis to close out my AND().